# Error "cannot open display" when starting wireshark on Ubuntu command line

Tags: wireshark

I have installed wireshark on Ubuntu, When I run it:

```
/usr/bin/wireshark
```

I get an error:

```
(wireshark:27945): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I want to run wireshark on the command prompt.

I don't want to use the UI.  I'm not sure why it is complaining about a display, I want to run it on a port.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try **tshark** - which is a "console based wireshark" which is part of wireshark project.

You should read Read [man tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

For example to capture http packet on 80 port run:

```
tshark -f 'tcp port 80 and http'
```

P.S. Example was fixed to use capture filter instead of display filter.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking. also how can I capture and get the HTTP Messages

Comment: The -R option is for display filter, not capture filter. For capture filter, try:        tshark  -f "http"

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu, running wireshark complains about display:

```
el@apollo:~$ wireshark
(wireshark:20619): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Set the DISPLAY environment variable:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/bin/wireshark
```

Then it works:

```
el@apollo:~$ wireshark -Y
wireshark: option requires an argument -- 'Y'

Usage: wireshark [options] ... [ <infile> ]

Capture interface:
  -i <interface>           name or idx of interface (def: first non-loopback)
  -f <capture filter>      packet filter in libpcap filter syntax
  -s <snaplen>             packet snapshot length (def: 65535)
  -p                       don't capture in promiscuous mode
  -k                       start capturing immediately (def: do nothing)
  -S                       update packet display when new packets are captured
  -l                       turn on automatic scrolling while -S is in use
  -I                       capture in monitor mode, if available
  -B <buffer size>         size of kernel buffer (def: 2MB)
  -y <link type>           link layer type (def: first appropriate)
  -D                       print list of interfaces and exit
  -L                       print list of link-layer types of iface and exit
```

wireshark is an X application, so it needs to know where to send the X11 display output.